# How to format code on stack overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Hello all,

Sorry for putting this insane question but I am stuck on this since long time.
Whenever I put code on stack overflow I always use "'" (single quotes) at the start and end of each line of code which is tedious and probability wrost of all available option.
How can we format multiple lines of code together instead of using "'" on every line ?

I observed many other newbies also facing this same issue.
Most of the time other experienced users edits the question.

Thanks,

Ajinkya.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out our FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for information on posting questions. Short answer: indent each line of code by two spaces, and it will be automatically formatted for you.

Comment: @bob: sorry it was pre copied text which got pasted in between.

Comment: @Bob should be 4, not two.

Comment: @vcsjones -- I _know_ it's four spaces! I have no idea why I wrote two! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround inline code with `back-ticks`, begin blocks of code with 4 spaces or a tab. Done!

Example:

```
Surround inline code with `back-ticks`,...
```

(Preceding line begins with four spaces.)